# Capture then Save the Image to Gallery not working Sometimes

Tags: android, camera, save, gallery, android-mediascanner

I have a method to start the camera and take a photo (**working with API 24 and Higher**)  :

```
public void invokeCamera()
{
    // create the image Uri
    Uri pictureUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getContext(),getContext().getPackageName() + ".provider",createImageFile());


    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

    // tell the camera where to save
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,pictureUri);

    // permission for saving the image
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);

    startActivityForResult(intent,CAPTURE_REQ_CODE);
}
```

creating the image File:

```
private File createImageFile() {

    File picturesDirectory  = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);

    String imgName = "myImageName_0X0Y02_test.jpg";

    return  new File(picturesDirectory.getPath(),"picture" + imgName );

}
```

- **the problem is** :

this code is working without errors but sometimes i can't see the image in the Gallery , sometimes when i open the gallery after about 10 mins i see it there ! this is weird and i'm confused , am i missing something ?

- All permissions are granted (Camera and full access to Storage)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you work with API 24 and higher, I will provide the code for it only. Basically, you need to tell the media scanner that a file was added so it can scan and add it straight away:

```
public static void scanMediaForChanges(Context context, File file){
    MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(context,
            new String[]{file.toString()}, null,
            new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
                public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
                    Log.i("ExternalStorage", "Scanned " + path + ":");
                    Log.i("ExternalStorage", "-> uri=" + uri);
                }
            });
}
```

Comment: Best answer , should i call this method on onActivityResult ?

Comment: @LovingAndroid glad I could help :) yeah, personally I call it in `onActivityResult` right after I check if the result is ok `if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {`

Comment: should i worry when i use this method with API 23 and lower ? i don't see error for now : )

Comment: @LovingAndroid I believe with API lower than 19 you should send a broadcast, something like that `sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, Uri.fromFile(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));` I am not sure about the second argument though, but it should work.

Comment: thank you but the first method works like a charm :) but i will take this note

Comment: @LovingAndroid no problem :)

Answer (score -2):

You are number #### with this problem. You should tell the media store about your new file.

To do that invoke the media scanner for your file.

Code has been posted a ### times. So google.

Comment: this is not an answer you should have posted this as a comment

Comment: What a nonsense. I told the cause of the problem and how to solve it. And left something for you to do. A real answer.

Comment: telling me to search s not an answer , it's a comment

Comment: If you think it is a repeat then mark it appropriately with answered question. IMO, lashing out on OP in your answer does not add any value to community.